# I get black screen instead of photo

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery, circleimage

I got problem with my image loading in my Fragment, when i chose place to search for image and pick the picture instead of it i get the black circle, this is my code:

```
civ = view.findViewById(R.id.circle_profile);

civ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent GaleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(GaleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }
});

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        CircleImageView imageView =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.circle_profile);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:id="@+id/circle_profile"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    />
```

It's looks like the border color only left

Comment: Have you check picturePath value  ?

Comment: For me its looks fine </storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170930_120008.jpg>

Comment: you can use the image picker libraries for example https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker

Comment: There is no better solution then use libraries

Comment: Have you try to use Image loading library like Glide,ImageLoader to load local image ?

Comment: Nope, only try this way, because i thought that would be enought and simple solution

Comment: I think you should at least try Glide for image loading and it's very easy.

Comment: Okay i will test it, will post after

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol "GlideApp" but i upload dependencies and repositories

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that in your code:
`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)` returns `null` maybe because the size of image is large

I suggest using `BitmapFactory.Options` and pass it inside [`decodeFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) function with `BitmapFactory.Options` as second parameter.

**EDIT:**

`BitmapFactory.Options` can have code like below:

```
// Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;


   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);

int photoW= bmOptions.outWidth;
int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

// Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

//Determine how much to scale down the image
int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

//Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the view
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And what should i give as an option ?

Comment: i have edited my answer with `BitmapFactory.Options` code

Comment: picturePath should i write like this ? ""@drawable/profile"

Comment: No. It should be String(like you have it in question). Please go through Syntax here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)

Comment: Thaks a lot that help me so much